# Help finding a specific factor of p + 1

Tags: number-theory

Conjecture: Let $p$ be a prime and $p + 1$ is not a semiprime, $p + 1$ has a factor of the form $q + 1$ where $q$ is prime.

I don't know whether this is right or not. I'm trying to prove it but I'm getting stuck. Here's what I've tried:

Let $D(x) = \{y : y | x\}$, $P(x) = \{ p + 1 : p$ is prime and $p < x \}$, $N(x) = \{ y : y \not | x$ and $y \not \in P(x) \}$. I wanted to show that if $x$ is not a semiprime and is a shifted prime, then $D(x) \bigcap P(x)$ is not empty. The way I tried to do this is to show that $|D(x)| + |P(x)| + |N(x)| > x$. I'm thinking a lower bound or an upper bound argument might help but i have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I realized that 6  is a semiprime divisible by 2 + 1. I also realize that if p + 1 is such that if $q | (p + 1)$ then $q^n \not | (p + 1)$ for n > 1 and all prime  then it won't hold.

Comment: @AndréNicolas 98/14 = 7

Comment: @user265855: Sorry, wonky arithmetic.

Comment: You will want to restrict to *proper* factors $q+1$, otherwise $q=p$.

Comment: @ccorn you're right, i should have clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you restrict to *proper* factors $q+1$, the smallest counterexample is $p=109$.

Found by a tiny Pari/GP script:

```
forprime(p=2, 200,
    N = p+1;
    if (vecsum(factor(N)[,2])<3, next());
    fordiv(N, d,
        if (d == N, next());
        if (ispseudoprime(d-1), next(2)));
    print(p))
```

Comment: ... and I could write `bigomega(N)` for `vecsum(factor(N)[,2])` ...